# defining a global ofstream in windows form

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, ofstream

I need to do sth like this:

```
 #include <fstream>

    ...


ofstream myStream

    private: System::Void start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //open ofstream
                 }

    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //write to ofstream
    }
```

is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried that makes you think you can't do this? It seems straightforward enough to me. The `ofstream` isn't global; it's just an instance variable of your class.

Comment: I tried to declare ofstream as shown in the code above. But this is not allowed. I currently switched to Streamwriter, but I prefer to use ofstream.

Comment: What did the declaration look like? What was the error?

Comment: Check my code for the declaration. The error is: "error C4368: cannot define 'myStream' as a member of managed 'Data_Logger::Form1': mixed types are not supported"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet shows where you wanted to declare it, but not what the declaration looked like. Anyway, the issue is that you can't use unmanaged (C++ native) objects in managed (.NET CLR) code. You could possibly declare an `ofstream*` variable, but not an `ofstream` or `ofstream&`.

If you want to use `ofstream` rather than `System.IO.StreamWriter`, you'll have to create a class in a separate containing only hative code, and instantiate that class from within your .NET code. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35041/Mixing-NET-and-native-code) is a CodeProject article addressing this.